# Resizing a JFrame to fit added components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm making a program for fun, it's basically a computer navigation GUI, details not required :)

Anyway, so far, I have a button called "new button" that, when clicked, it creates a new button named "test", to an infinite amount. Right now, i have my GUI set up like this:

Class Main extends JPanel (the main panel that holds everything in it, size set as)
`Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 200);`
`setPreferredSize(size);`

JFrame holding the Main JPanel, called like:

```
panel.frame = new JFrame();
panel.frame.setResizable(false);
panel.frame.setTitle(panel.title);
panel.frame.add(panel);
panel.frame.pack();
panel.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
panel.frame.setVisible(true);
```

So, how would i have the JFrame/JPanel set their size based on the components inside it? I've tried to use panel.frame.pack(); but i get an error most of the time, and the other times it doesnt wrap, it is just a staight line. I want it to resize in the form of a square. Any ideas? Sorry if my question isnt clear/poorly phrased, i've always had issues articulating questions online, much better in person cause i can use my hands! :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class Main extends JPanel (the main panel that holds everything in it, size set as) Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 200); setPreferredSize(size);

Don't set the preferred size of the panel. The layout manager will determine the preferred size based on the components that you add to the panel.

> and the other times it doesnt wrap,

The default layout manager for a JPanel is a FlowLayout. It is not designed to wrap automatically. Maybe use a different layout manager. Or you can try the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which extends FlowLayout to provide dynamic wrapping.

> I've tried to use panel.frame.pack(); but i get an error most of the time

What error. I've never seen an error when using the pack() method.

Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) if you need more help.